# Stepping through Multi-dimensional Array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, serial-port, uart

I have a piece of code that runs on an embedded system. Its job is to convert some ASCII characters into proprietary data. The data is stored in a multi-dimensional array and what appears to be the problem, although I am unable to confirm this with the hardware debugger, is that the bit variable is staying at value 2. This code works the first two times it is run, but on the third run it breaks and returns starts sending wrong data through the UART interface. I though maybe someone else analyzing this might be able to see what I'm missing. This is C99 which I am not too familiar with. Bleow is the entire function, but I think the problem is with the for statement?? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
void simple_uart_putstring(uint8_t *str, uint16_t length)
{
    //send data bits
    uint_fast8_t index = 0;
    uint8_t ch = str[index++];
    uint_fast8_t bitCount = 0;
    int index2 = 0;
    int bit = 0;

    if (length > 1)
    {
        while (length >= index)
        {
            if (bitCount < 2)
            {
                if (length < 10)
                {
                    //send sync bits
                    simple_uart_put(254);
                    simple_uart_put(223);
                    bitCount = 2;
                } else {
                    //send sync bits and add scrolling
                    simple_uart_put(254);
                    simple_uart_put(222);
                    bitCount = 2;
                }
            }
            //send each bit for each letter in the string
            for (uint_fast8_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                index2 = (int)ch;
                bit = (int)i;
                simple_uart_put(matrix[index2 - 32][bit]);
                bitCount++;
            }
            ch = str[index++];
        }
        //the main controller is expecting 150 bits total to continue to send bit until 150
        while (bitCount <= 150)
        {
            simple_uart_put(0);
            bitCount++;
            if(bitCount >= 150)
            {
                bitCount = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        bitCount = 0;
    }
}
```

And here is a sample of the array:

```
 const uint8_t matrix[59][5] = 
    {
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, //space  
        { 0, 125, 0, 0, 0}, //!  
        { 0, 112, 0, 112, 0}, //"
{127, 127, 127, 127, 127 }, //# 
                                           { 18, 42, 107, 36, 0}, //$
                                           { 50, 52, 22, 38, 0}, //%
                                           { 38, 89, 57, 6, 9}, //&
                                           { 64, 48, 0, 0, 0}, //'
                                           { 0, 0, 62, 65, 0}, //(
                                           { 0, 65, 62, 0, 0}, //)
                                           { 20, 8, 62, 8, 20}, //*
                                           { 0, 8, 28, 8, 0}, //+
                                           { 1, 6, 0, 0, 0}, //,
                                           { 0, 8, 8, 8, 0}, //-
                                           { 3, 3, 0, 0, 0}, //.
                                           { 2, 4, 8, 16, 32}, //
                                           { 62, 69, 73, 62, 0}, //0
                                           { 1, 33, 127, 1, 0}, //1
                                           { 35, 67, 69, 49, 0}, //2
                                           { 34, 73, 73, 54, 0}, //3
                                           { 12, 20, 36, 127, 0}, //4
                                           { 114, 81, 81, 78, 0}, //5
                                           { 30, 41, 73, 6, 0}, //6
                                           { 64, 71, 72, 112, 0}, //7
                                           { 54, 73, 73, 54, 0}, //8
                                           { 48, 73, 74, 60, 0}, //9
                                           { 0, 54, 54, 0, 0}, //:
                                           { 0, 1, 54, 0, 0}, //;
                                           { 0, 8, 20, 34, 0}, //<
                                           { 0, 20, 20, 20, 0}, //=
                                           { 0, 34, 20, 8, 0}, //>
                                           { 32, 64, 69, 72, 48}, //?
                                           { 62, 65, 93, 93, 112}, //@

                                           { 63, 72, 72, 63, 0 }, //a
                                           { 127, 73, 73, 54, 0 }, //b
                                           { 62, 65, 65, 34, 0}, //c
                                           { 127, 65, 34, 28, 0 }, //d
                                           { 127, 73, 73, 65, 0}, //e
                                           { 127, 72, 72, 64, 0}, //f
                                           { 62, 65, 73, 47, 0}, //g
                                           { 127, 8, 8, 127, 0}, //h
                                           { 0, 65, 127, 65, 0},//i
                                           { 6, 65, 126, 64, 0}, //j
                                           { 127, 8, 20, 99, 0}, //k
                                           { 127, 1, 1, 1, 0}, //l
                                           { 127, 32, 24, 32, 127}, //m
                                           { 127, 16, 8, 127, 0}, //n
                                           { 62, 65, 65, 62, 0}, //o
                                           { 127, 72, 72, 48, 0}, //p
                                           { 60, 70, 66, 61, 0}, //q
                                           { 127, 76, 74, 49, 0}, //r
                                           { 50, 73, 73, 38, 0}, //s
                                           { 0, 64, 127, 64, 0}, //t
                                           { 126, 1, 1, 126, 0},
                                           { 127, 1, 2, 124, 0},
                                           { 126, 1, 6, 1, 126},
                                           { 99, 28, 28, 99, 0},
                                           { 112, 8, 8, 127, 0},
                                           { 71, 73, 81, 97, 0}};
```

And the uart send method:

```
void simple_uart_put(uint8_t cr)
{
  NRF_UART0->TXD = (uint8_t)cr;

  while (NRF_UART0->EVENTS_TXDRDY!=1)
  {
    // Wait for TXD data to be sent
  }

  NRF_UART0->EVENTS_TXDRDY=0;
}
```

An example of this working would be if the input string is "AB" and the length = 2;
It should send the following bytes via UART:

```
{254, 223, 63, 72, 72, 63, 0, 127, 73, 73, 54, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, etc....}
```

The first two bytes are sync bytes, the next five come from the array `matrix[33][0 to 4]` because ASCII 'A' = 65 and 65-32 = 33. Then the next five come from ASCII 'B' = 66 and 66 - 32 = 34 so they are sent from `matrix[34][0 to 4]`. Then the next n = 150 - bitNumber are sent as 0 because the main controller is expecting 150 bytes always.

Comment: It's very difficult to know what the problem is unless you tell us what it's *meant* to do. What is the on-the-wire protocol?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for, but I haven ow added a few code comments. The purpose of this method is to convert a string into data for a matrix display, then pass it along to the display controller via UART.

Comment: This is not a complete function.  Edit your post with the complete function, including argument list and return type, just as it is in your project.  That would help to follow input to output.  Include an example of (a non-proprietary example) of a typical input value that this function would be expected to process.

Comment: I have included the parameters, and this function has no return type (void) I have added the simple_uart_put method as well now

Comment: The problem shouldn't be in the for statement unless somehow casting uint_fast8_t to int isn't compatible. This seems like a hard to believe scenario.

Comment: Is it possible some other function is accessing matrix at the same time as this function?

Comment: I have added an example scenario... I don't believe it can be accessed by anything else, unless it is open in another thread. Also it always fails on the third run, 1st and 2nd work fine...

Comment: Is there a reason to believe that it isn't open on another thread?

Comment: it shouldn't be, if for some reason the loop never breaks then it still could be open in another thread even after the function is called again?? I don't know really?

Comment: @TannerEwing - (repeated from below) Also, in the line: simple_uart_put(matrix[index2 - 32][bit]); since index2, I believe, is always 98, the arguement will always be 97-32, 65, or ASCII A. Is this correct behavior as far as you know?

Answer (score 1):

***See edit at bottom***

Without having definitions for all functions, I cannot completely analyze this, however there are a couple of suspicious things:

***1)*** this declaration is odd:

```
  uint_fast8_t index = 0;
  uint8_t ch = str[index++]; //always sets ch to first character of input "str" then increments index.
```

***NOTE:*** corrected comment on previous line.

***2)*** although the comment indicates "each bit for each letter in the string" it only handle 5:

```
        for (uint_fast8_t i = 0; i < 5; i++){...} //what if lenth of input is less than 5?
```

Suggest changing to:

```
        for (uint_fast8_t i = 0; i < length; i++){...}  //used second argument "length"
```

***3)*** Finally, it seems that null terminating the string should follow the for loop, but:  (see comments in line) (Also, input arguments used were "abc", 4)

```
    for (uint_fast8_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        index2 = (int)ch; //ch inits to first char in str, and indexes through
        bit = (int)i;
        //simple_uart_put(matrix[index2 - 32][bit]);
        bitCount++;
    }
    ch = str[index++]; //terminates in second character of input "b' in this case  
    //I think this should null terminate with '\0' if it is to be treated as a C string,
    //but because, as you say, this is "proprietary", I am not sure.
```

***EDIT***

I think the problem may be that you have declared the variable matrix with what looks like sufficient room, but only initialized it with three rows of data:

```
const uint8_t matrix[59][5] = 
{
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, //space  
    { 0, 125, 0, 0, 0}, //!  
    { 0, 112, 0, 112, 0}, //"
}; //have only initialized matrix[0], matrix[1] and matrix[2]
```

The remaining 53 rows of data, although owned by you, have not been initialized that I can see.  So, when you say:

*the next five come from the array matrix[33][0 to 4] because ASCII 'A' = 65 and 65-32 = 33. Then the next five come from ASCII 'B' = 66 and 66 - 32 = 34 so they are sent from matrix[34][0 to 4]*

That suggests what ever random number happens to be occupying those uninitialized memory locations, are what is being written out in the line:

```
simple_uart_put(matrix[index2 - 32][bit]);
```

***EDIT 2***  (See comment to explain)

Here is my main(), and commented simple_uart_putstring():

```
int     main()
{
    uint8_t *str;
    int len=3;

    str = malloc(3); //extra char for terminating null byte

    strcpy(str, "AB");
    simple_uart_putstring(str, 2);
    free(str);
}

void simple_uart_putstring(uint8_t *str, uint16_t length)
{
    //send data bits
  uint_fast8_t index = 0;
  uint8_t ch = str[index++]; //ch inits to first char in str, and indexes through
    uint_fast8_t bitCount = 0;
    int index2 = 0;
    int bit = 0;

    if (length > 1)
    {
        while (length >= index)
        {
            if (bitCount < 2)
            {
                    if (length < 10)
                    {
                        //send sync bits
                        //simple_uart_put(254);
                        //simple_uart_put(223);
                        bitCount = 2;
                    } else {
                        //send sync bits and add scrolling
                        //simple_uart_put(254);
                        //simple_uart_put(222);
                        bitCount = 2;
                    }   
            }
            //send each bit for each letter in the string
            for (uint_fast8_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                index2 = (int)ch; //
                bit = (int)i;
                /*simple_uart_put(*/matrix[index2 - 32][bit];//);break here to view "matrix[index2 - 32][bit]"
                bitCount++;
            }
            ch = str[index++]; //
        }
        //the main controller is expecting 150 bits total to continue to send bit until 150
            while (bitCount <= 150)
        {
                //simple_uart_put(0);
                bitCount++;
                if(bitCount >= 150)
                {
                    bitCount = 0;
                    break;
                }
        }
        bitCount = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The fact that `ch` is not modified within the loop is the relevant bit here.

Comment: ch should not be modified inside the loop, ch steps through each letter and the for loop gets each of 5 bits for that letter.

Comment: @JohnBode - I assume no pun intended?  "relevant bit"

Comment: @TannerEwing - okay, that would explain why the index is hard coded to only look at the first 5 bits then, instead of looking at `length` bits.  Why is there even a parameter for length then I wonder?  Also, adds mystery to why even have the line `index2 = (int)ch;`

Comment: @TannerEwing - (repeated from above) Also, in the line: simple_uart_put(matrix[index2 - 32][bit]); since index2, I believe, is always 98, the arguement will always be 97-32, 65, or ASCII A. Is this correct behavior as far as you know?

Comment: @ryyker I am not sure how you get that the index2 is always 98? that index seems to be working fine, it the letter ch = 'E' I get index2=69. Also the length is there to determine how long the total char array is. I need to know when to end the loop, and how many character need converted to matrix data.

Comment: @TannerEwing - I agree.  I did not correct my comments, but did correct the post yesterday after running your code on my system. I do have one question:  Do you know why `const uint8_t matrix[59][5] =...` is delclared this way when it only had 3 rows?   In any case, I am still looking at this.  But I am also at a job today, so may not be able to give it much attention just now.  Sorry for delay, but stay tuned.  If next time I come back, this is still not got an answer, I will keep working it.

Comment: @ryyker The array is declared that way because it actually contains 59 elements. I truncated it to save space on this form, but now I have added it to prevent confusion. Thanks for all your help! I look forward to your answer.

Comment: @TannerEwing - Thank you for remainder of `matrix` definition.  See my final edit (EDIT 2). I ran this with an input of AB, and got an output of precisely what you said it should be. Note: I commented out calls that I did not need, and used break points to determine what the value being sent would be, as I do not have a definition for (nor do I need one) for the struct NRF_UART0. The code I have posted is essentially the same as yours, with exception of commented out lines and a comment telling you where to look at matrix value.